# Get facebook profile picture of user that is not a friend

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-android-sdk

I have an android app that support facebook login too, and each logged user has a profile picture (custom, or facebook profile picture), and each user is register on my server too. 
Now if i need to retrieve picture of user friends, i have no problem, because i make everithing inside app by using ProfilePictureView object of last Android Facebook SDK and friends id:

```
fb_image = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.fb_friend_thumbnail);
fb_image.setProfileId(friend_id);
```

If i need to retrieve facebook picture of other user, i call a php script that should return information for get picture. 
It's a good practice to send user's id as result of script (so app retrieve picture by using ProgilePictureView), or it's better to use php sdk for get picture, encode it and sent it as result?

Comment: you are using facebook sdk?

Comment: Yes, i'm using last facebook sdk for android and for php

Comment: whether you can get user id right?

Comment: Yes, i can get facebook id of user friend's directly on my app, but i have also facebook id of other users (stored on my server)

Comment: check my answer.  https://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+ "/picture?type=small you can use this to get profile picture. change based on your requirement whether you need image in small or large to display.. and you said you have user id saved in server. so retrieve andpass that user id in this url and display. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get user id of facebook friends, then you can get profile picture of users.

```
  Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
                    try {
                        if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) if (user != null) {
                            String fbFirstName = user.getFirstName();
                            String fbLastName = user.getLastName();
                            String dateOfBirth = user.getBirthday();
                            String userId=user.getId();
                            URL image_url=new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+ "/picture?type=small");
                            Bitmap bitmap=null;
                            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            String fbEmail = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                            Session.getActiveSession()
                                    .closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                            getActivity().finish();
                        }
                    }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e(Constants.TAG_EXCEPTION, e.toString());
                        }

                    }

            });

    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: I know how to retrieve facebook picture of friends. I would know what to do when i need pictures of user that is not friend of mine. If it's a good practice sent to app user id as response or not